# R dates "origin" must be supplied

Tags: r, date

My code:

```
axis.Date(1,sites$date, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Error:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied

Why is it asking me for the origin when I supplied it in the above code?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I suspect you meant:

```
axis.Date(1, as.Date(sites$date, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

as the 'x' argument to `as.Date()` has to be of type `Date`.

As an aside, this would have been appropriate as a follow-up or edit of your previous question.

Comment: 'x' argument to _axis_.Date(), no?

Comment: See `args(as.Date)` to see `x` there too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel do you think it's worth a quick edit in both question and answer to change the date to `"1970-01-01"`. I guess a lot of people arrive here wanting that origin (rather than the one in the OP). Changing the date wouldn't affect the syntactic troubleshooting you provide, but would ensure noone accidentally sets origin to ~1960 when they may not have intended to

Comment: Whoops. Good catch.  Decade-only typo!  Better yet, these days use `anytime::anydate(sites$date)` :-)

Comment: Whoops^2. Thanks to @stevec to catch a typo in my fix. I'll find a rock to hide under.

Comment: Just for clarification, this was to convert some dates that had a SAS origin of 1/1/1960 FYI. I know that R uses 1970.

Comment: It's more generally seen as a 'POSIX' start date for all things Unix and following Unix standards, as R is.  Or even 'Unix time' in short:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 24):

My R use 1970-01-01:

```
>as.Date(15103, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2011-05-09"
```

and this matches the calculation from

```
>as.numeric(as.Date(15103, origin="1970-01-01"))
```

Comment: Mine too, why each R uses different origin dates?

Comment: I know this is an old post. But whenever I run this I get `NA` all the way down my date column. My dates are in this format `20150521`

Comment: The person above needed as.Date(as.character(col), format="%Y%m%d") for future wanderers.

Answer (score 16):

So generally this has been solved, but you might get this error message because the date you use is not in the correct format.

I know this is an old post, but whenever I run this I get NA all the way down my date column. My dates are in this format 20150521 – NealC Jun 5 '15 at 16:06

If you have dates of this format just check the format of your dates with:

```
str(sides$date)
```

If the format is not a character, then convert it:

```
as.character(sides$date)
```

For as.Date, you won't need an origin any longer, because this is supplied for numeric values only. Thus you can use (assuming you have the format of NealC):

```
as.Date(as.character(sides$date),format="%Y%m%d")
```

I hope this might help some of you.

Answer (score 15):

Another option is the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- 15103
as_date(x, origin = lubridate::origin)
"2011-05-09"

y <- 1442866615
as_datetime(y, origin = lubridate::origin)
"2015-09-21 20:16:55 UTC"
```

From the docs:

> Origin is the date-time for 1970-01-01 UTC in POSIXct format. This date-time is the origin for the numbering system used by POSIXct, POSIXlt, chron, and Date classes.

Answer (score 7):

If you have both date and time information in the numeric value, then use `as.POSIXct`. Data.table package IDateTime format is such a case. If you use `fwrite` to save a file, the package automatically  converts date-times to idatetime format which is unix time. To convert back to normal format following can be done.

Example: Let's say you have a unix time stamp with date and time info: 1442866615

```
> as.POSIXct(1442866615,origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2015-09-21 16:16:54 EDT"
```

Answer (score 3):

by the way, the *zoo* package, if it is loaded, overrides the base as.Date() with its own which, by default, provides origin="1970-01-01".

(i mention this in case you find that sometimes you need to add the origin, and sometimes you don't.)