# R Date origin for formatting

Tags: r, date

I read [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792819/r-dates-origin-must-be-supplied) about using the `origin` to set the date start time. I am reading in from csv where the dates are the number of days and read in as factors.

```
Example: $ admin_date    : Factor w/ 318 levels "37362","37735"
```

I would like to convert to date formats to measure number of days and months between events. But when I try all of the different `origin` such as:

```
df$admin_date_new <- as.numeric(df$admin_date)
df$admin_date_new <- as.Date(df$admin_date, origin="1900/01/01")
```

I get the following:

```
 $ admin_date_new: Date, format: "1900-08-31"
```

**Is this something with finding the correct `origin` or is this when I am converting to `numeric`**

Is there a quick way to find the origin necessary? I read `help("as.Date")` and all I got was:

```
## date given as number of days since 1900-01-01 (a date in 1989)
as.Date(32768, origin = "1900-01-01")
## Excel is said to use 1900-01-01 as day 1 (Windows default) or
## 1904-01-01 as day 0 (Mac default), but this is complicated by Excel
## incorrectly treating 1900 as a leap year.
## So for dates (post-1901) from Windows Excel
as.Date(35981, origin = "1899-12-30") # 1998-07-05
## and Mac Excel
as.Date(34519, origin = "1904-01-01") # 1998-07-05
## (these values come from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214330)
```

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(df$admin_date))`

Comment: @Roland thanks. But this is producing dates in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give the expected result, but maybe this:

```
x <- factor(c("37362", "37735"))
y <- as.numeric(as.character(x))
as.Date(y, origin = "1900-01-01")
#[1] "2002-04-18" "2003-04-26"
```

If you don't know the origin, there is no way to find out just from your data.

Comment: thanks. This works great. I had to modify slightly: as.Date(y - 2, origin = "1900-01-01") --- since the conversion was adding two days to the final result.