# Equivalent of Datevec function of Matlab for R

Tags: r, date, time, data-conversion

I am trying to find an equivalent function of Datevec of Matlab for R. I know there is one in the solidearthtide package, but this package is not available for the last version of R.

Any suggestion in how to convert an ordinal number into a vector DAY/MONTH/YEAR?

Comment: Likely a dupe of one of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48893681/3358272 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/33371933/3358272

Comment: I'm sure this is very straightforward if only you would edit your question to give sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I used `(as.Date(data, origin = "0000-01-01.00-00-00"))` to change from serial number into string date and it worked fine. there is also another function in the same course of action you can check it out such as `as.dates`, `as.numeric`, etc.